# string.Substring command not working

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I have a dropdown list with a list of printers, I want to get the first three digits from the `drowdownlist.SelectedItem.Text`, the reason behind this is that I need to calculate the rotation code of an item.

This is the code:

```
string[] plantname = Printerlist.SelectedItem.Text.Split('-');
string plantvalue = plantname[0].ToString();
if (plantvalue.Substring(0,3).ToLower() == "abk"){
   rotation_plant = "9";
 }
 else if (plantvalue.Substring(0, 3).ToLower() == "cor")
 {
    rotation_plant = "3";
 }
 else if (plantvalue.Substring(0, 3).ToLower() == "iok")
 {
    rotation_plant = "0";
 }
 else if (plantvalue.Substring(0, 3).ToLower() == "moc")
 {
    rotation_plant = "6";
 }
 else if (plantvalue.Substring(0, 3).ToLower() == "tes")
 {
    rotation_plant = "1";
 }
```

in debug I see the plantvalue :
[image: plantvalue]

but the substring of above must equal "tes" but:
[image: it is not]

**I did a rebuild, I closed the application and reopened it but its still not working, has anyone faced similar issue if so how did you over come it please help....**

Comment: Quick suggestion - I would pull `plantvalue.Substring(0,3).ToLower()` into its own variable to make it easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Besides the point but it triggers my performance OCD. Why are you repeating the `Substring` and `ToLower` operations?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Yes, performance is one thing, but the code could also be more simple and readable with `switch (plantvalue.Substring(0,3).ToLower()) { case "abk": /* ... */ }`, in my opinion.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen maybe roslyn can't figure that out, but these ARE pure functions, and as such they could theoretically be cached. at any rate, they are REALLY cheap methods to call on such a small string, and as such you should care more about the duplication of code and the worsened readability.

Comment: Can we ask, what is the numerical value `(ushort)plantvalue[0]`, what is `(ushort)plantvalue[1]`, what is `(ushort)plantvalue[2]`, and what is `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`? What is `(ushort)plantvalue.Substring(0, 3)[0]` and so on? Maybe the string contains an "invisible" character or other unexpected UTF-16 code unit.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I absolutely agree, but my performance OCD alarm went off first. In reality, this will probably not be a significant performance problem in most cases and the redundancy should be addressed regardless.

Comment: What is not working? All you have shown is a screen capture of the value of `plantvalue`. Is `rotation_plant` not being set to `"1"` after the `if` body is executed?

Comment: @Setsu yes that right, the below answer worked for me, I was trying to write one less additional line of code but turns out you need to first take the substring value set it to a string then use this string in the if condition.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem, but all I wanted to point out was that your original code had no error. See example: [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3oWyl7)

Comment: @Setsu that is very strange buddy but why the same code in my question the substring property is not doing its job, I unnecessarily had to set it to another string then then take the substring of that?? the result had to be "tes" but as you can see in my question the substring property gives me the whole thing (Test(63))

Comment: Alex's answer already explains this, but when you moused over the `Substring().ToLower()` line you were actually viewing the value of `plantvalue`, NOT the final result of those function calls. My point all along was that you were checking the wrong thing; you should have checked to see if `rotation_plant` was set to `"1"`. In any case your fix seems to have solved whatever problem you were having (because, again, the code as presented has no errors) and caching the result is better code anyways.

Comment: @Setsu yea the rotation_plant was not getting set to 1 that's why I had to debug the code and then saw that substring(0,3) of test(63) was not equal to tes so it would skip over the enter if else. anyways thanks for your help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the *Substring* method, in your case, returns a new string, which will have the charts from index 0 to 2.

In debugger, you still check the *plantvalue* variable, and not the result of the *Substring* method.
Try putting the substring in a new variable, i.e:

```
string lowerThreeLetters = plantvalue.Substring(0, 3).ToLower();
```

This way, you will be able to see the 3 first letters in debug by hovering over the *lowerThreeLetters* variable, and also, will do the calculations of the Substring only once, and not for each if statement.